# What is the difference between DEA and SFA in terms of data used?

Tags: nonparametric

I read that Data Envelopment Analysis (DEA) is non-parametric approach while Stochastic Frontier Analysis (SFA) is parametric approach.

Does it make any difference using one of the approaches depending on data type and number of cases.

Are there any constrains to use parametric approach if I choose SFA?

Or what is the logic of choosing one of the methods over other one?